# I am trying to replace images in pdf but not all of them are getting done

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfbox

```
public static Image makeBlackAndWhitePng(PdfImageObject image) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\anahata\\Desktop\\text analysis\\14-1.png");
    BufferedImage bi = image.getBufferedImage();
    BufferedImage x = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    x = ImageIO.read(f);
    BufferedImage newBi = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY);
    newBi.getGraphics().drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(x, "png", baos);
    return Image.getInstance(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

Comment: Is your question about iText OR about pdfbox?

Comment: Please provide your PDF file.

Comment: And please explain what exactly *"not all of them are getting done"* shall mean. Are some images unchanged? Or lost? Or defaced?

Comment: Your code does not show any modification in a PDF. Your graphics device is not disposed. You create a BufferedImage (x) that you never use, and then you overwrite it. You save an image just to reload it immediately after. (Image.getInstance accepts an awt image too). All this is not related to your problem, but it looks as if you're making your own life more difficult than it should be.